# Why trailing zero added when use .Tostring()

Tags: c#, asp.net, math, decimal

When try to return object of type decimal using `Command.ExecuteScalar()`
and use the "returned object" `.Tostring()` a trailing zero appears to the value

ex.

```
dbCmd.CommandText = "select .12345 from dual" ;
 object returnValue = dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
 string expectedValue =  returnValue.ToString();
```

> The expected result : .12345
>
> The actual result  : .123450

I notice that trailing zero added only if the "the number of digits after the decimal point" is odd
 ex.
    if the command text is "select .123456 from dual" ;

> The expected result : .123456
>
> The actual result  : .123456

Comment: Which language is this in ? Might be useful information :)

Comment: Looks like formatting is set to 6 decimal places. If you expect .1234 does it give .123400 ?

Comment: Does it matter? From a purely numeric standpoint, both the expected and actual results are the same number.

Comment: What is the type of the database field, and what is the type of the returned value?

Comment: @ Maxime : Language C#
@ Sith : Its not formatting because if i write .123 the actual value will be .1230
@ Damien : Yes its matter because i have validation length on the textbox (which we set the value on it) so the extra zero produce validation error which is wrong
@ Guffa : return value is decimal and i need to convert it to string